# php Getting files list &(ampersand) character error

Tags: php, file, list, get, character

I have code for getting files list in php, but if file name contain & character it doesn't display that file.
Here's the code:

Ps. I'm not php programmer and I really don't know what is this error.
All help will be very appreciated
Thanks so much in advance.

```
<?php
include_once('config.inc.php');
$current_dir = 'root';
if(array_key_exists('directory',$_POST)) {
$current_dir = $_POST['directory'];
}

// Creating a new XML using DOMDocument
 $file_list = new DOMDocument('1.0');
 $xml_root = $file_list->createElement('filelist');
 $xml_root = $file_list->appendChild($xml_root);

 // Setting the 'currentPath' attribute of the XML
 $current_path = $file_list->createAttribute('currentPath');
 $current_path->appendChild($file_list->createTextNode($current_dir));
 $xml_root->appendChild($current_path);

 // Replacing the word 'root' with the real root path
 $current_dir = substr_replace($current_dir, $root, 0, 4);

 $di = new DirectoryIterator($current_dir);

 // Creating the XML using DirectoryIterator
 while($di->valid())
 {
if(false == $di->isDot())
{
    if($di->isDir() && true != in_array($di->getBasename(),$h_folders))
    {
        $fl_node = $file_list->createElement('dir');
        $xml_root->appendChild($fl_node);
    }else if($di->isFile() && true !== in_array($di->getBasename(),$h_files) 
            &&  true !== in_array(get_ext($di->getBasename()),$h_types))
    {
        $fl_node = $file_list->createElement('file');
        $xml_root->appendChild($fl_node);
    }else 
    {
        $di->next();
            continue;
    }
    $name = $file_list->createElement('name',$di->getBasename());
    $fl_node->appendChild($name);
    $path = substr_replace($di->getRealPath(), 'root', 0, strlen($root));
    $path_node = $file_list->createElement('path', $path);
    $fl_node->appendChild($path_node);
    $di->next();
}else $di->next();
}

function get_ext($filename)
{
$exp = '/^(.+)\./';
return preg_replace($exp,'',$filename);
}

 // Returning the XML to Flash.
 echo $file_list->saveXML();
 ?>
```

Comment: Could you include your code in the question, please?

Comment: hi, sorry code is too long and I'm not able to post it :(

Comment: You can edit your question to include up to about 30k of code; you just need to include the relevant parts in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` character is used in HTML to write entities.

If you want to display arbitrary text in HTML, you need to *escape* it by calling `htmlentities()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you give some source I can help, file content not file name.
Example how get list of files:

```
$c = "/some/path/to/file/here";
if(is_dir($c)){
foreach(scandir($c) as $file){
  if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
    $d = $c.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
    echo " \"". realpath($d)  ."\"\n";
    }
}
}
```